# Activity starting again when AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode is changed

Tags: android, android-dark-theme

```
preferences = getSharedPreferences("name", MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (preferences.getBoolean("dark", false)) {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    } else {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
    }
```

So, I have implemented dark theme in my app and then saving the state in shared preferences and then when I restart the app I have to check the state and apply the theme accordingly but when I did so the activity is starting again on it's own

Don't have any idea how to solve this thing!!!

Comment: can you post your `styles.xml` here ?

Comment: I have 2 style files first is the regular one and second is the night mood style

Comment: If you're not using the night mode style it's possible your app is crashing becasue of that. We need to see `AndroidManifest` and `styles.xml`.

Comment: Where are you calling the above code?

Comment: I am calling this function so that I can change the mode of y app according to the shared preference file